# Spring redirect after servlet forward not passing model

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

I have a Portal that combines Spring controllers with a couple of regular servlets.

In the screen the user has a list from which he/she selects a credit card in order to see a report of the transactions of that card. As an extra security measure, I avoid sending the credit card in any request to the client so I have a list of credit cards numbers masked that I send to the user and in the request sent by the user I receive a record id which I use to determine which credit card is querying.

In a controller (**ReportController**), I have a method that process this input and call (locally) the servlet in charge of processing the report (**ReportServlet**). If there is any error in the processing it should return it to the screen using the *model* param "*error*". This last part isn't working.

If there is an error in the **ReportServlet** it is not returned to the screen. If I comment the forward line (and force an error) it works, but after doing the forwarding it doesn't. What I'm doing wrong?

Here's the code:

**ReportController**

```
try {
               ...

                if (cardholders == null || cardholders.size() < 2 || id <= 0) {
                    model.put("error","there's an error");
                    return CARDTRANSACTIONS_PATH;
                } else {
...
                    HttpUpdatetableRequestWrapper customRequest = new HttpUpdatetableRequestWrapper(request);
                    customRequest.setParameter("cardnumber", cardholder.getCardnumber());

                    request.getRequestDispatcher(config.getProperty("reportservlet")).forward((HttpServletRequest) customRequest, response);
                    String error = (String) session.getAttribute("error");
                    if(!(error == null || "".equals(error))){
                        throw new RuntimeException(error);                        
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                model.put("error", "there's an error");
            } finally{ return CARDTRANSACTIONS_PATH;}
```

Comment: If you're going to forward, you should return `null` form your controller instead of `CARDTRANSACTIONS_PATH` which I assume is some String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your controller returns, Spring will give the model to an [`AbstractView`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/AbstractView.html) which will decompose it and transfer the attributes over to the request. So when you are adding attributes to the model object in your controller, you're only adding them to a map with no relationship to the request. If you want those attributes to be available to the resource you forward to, you should add them directly to the request.

When you forward, you're expecting the resource you're forwarding to to handle the response, so you should make your controller return `null` in that situation, so that it doesn't do any further processing.